# Python: use of Counter in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

Given a dictionary of lists like this:
`d={0:[0.1,0.2,0.1], 1:[1.1,1.2,0.1], 2:[2.1,2.2,0.1]}`

I want to be able to count how many times each individual value appears in all lists. In the example given, the intended outcome would be:

`occurrences={0.1:4, 0.2:1, 1.1:1, 1.2:1, 2.1:1, 2.2:1}`

I was thinking of using `Counter` in a line like this:

`occurrences = Counter([k[0] for k in d.values()])`

but the output is `Counter({0.1: 1, 1.1: 1, 2.1: 1})`, meaning that the previous line only counts the occurrences of the first element of each list.

**How can I extend this count to all elements of all lists?**

Comment: Are the elements in your lists floats?  If so, you are going to need to define a tolerance in order to get meaningful results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't appear to care about the keys of the dict, you can just use a comprehension:

```
>>> Counter(v for sublist in d.values() for v in sublist)
Counter({0.1: 4, 0.2: 1, 1.1: 1, 1.2: 1, 2.1: 1, 2.2: 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put all the value lists in one flat list and then count. You can pass the dictionary's list of values to [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to *flatten* them:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

d={0:[0.1,0.2,0.1], 1:[1.1,1.2,0.1], 2:[2.1,2.2,0.1]}
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
print(c)
# Counter({0.1: 4, 0.2: 1, 1.2: 1, 2.2: 1, 1.1: 1, 2.1: 1})
```